# How many 3-vertex cliques are there in an incomplete and undirected graph with $N$ vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the following incomplete and undirected graph with 6 vertices

[image]

This graph has six 3-vertex cliques, or "inner triangles", and I want to know if there exists a general formula for how many internal triangles there are in any graph with $N$ vertices of the same "kind" as the one above. Unfortunately, I am having trouble pinpointing what kind of graph the one above actually is, since I cannot think of a defining feature (for example, not all vertices have the same degree). Maybe the defining feature is that no clique has more than 3 vertices?

All I can think of is other graphs of the same "kind" as the one above with a smaller or larger number of vertices. Here is the same kind of graph with 5 vertices and 3 inner triangles

[image]

and here is the same kind of graph with 7 vertices and 8 inner triangles

[image]

My questions are:

1. What do all of the graphs above have in common? I think it is that no clique has more than 3 vertices, but I am not sure if there is a better defining feature.
2. Is there a general formula for how many inner triangles there are for any graph with $N$ vertices of the same kind as the graphs above?
3. If there isn't a general formula, is there an algorithm that can compute the number of inner triangles?

Comment: I'd say they're triangulations of a rectangle where none of the triangles is itself triangulated.  That's a different point of view than the graph perspective, though.  Does it work?

Comment: Actually, the fact that the 4 corner vertices are arranged in a rectangle was unintentional. They don't necessarily need to be arranged like that. Will change the diagrams to reflect this. Nevertheless, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: So make it a quadrilateral.  I don't think it will make any difference in the counting will it?  There's linear transformation carrying the quadrilateral to a rectangle, and it will take a triangulation to a triangulation.

Comment: See the new graphs I've added. It doesn't necessarily need to be a quadrilateral either. I think the number of sides does play a role though.

Comment: I see that now.  It still seems to me like you're triangulating an $n$-gon, though.  Will all your graphs be planar?

Comment: Yes all graphs will be planar. Based on your suggestion and after a quick search, it seems that what I am doing is [point-set triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_triangulation), or more specifically, [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) of the points. According to Wikipedia, the Delaunay triangulation results in $O(N^{\left\lceil\frac{d}{2}\right\rceil})$ triangles in $d$ dimensions. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't think it's quite the same.  The Delauny triangulation has a restriction on points lying in the circumcircle of one of the other triangles, so it has metric restrictions that you don't.  I think your graphs are all *chordal*.  Also they're connected, and each vertex has degree at least two.

Comment: But if we ignore the edges between the vertices, and since the union of all the inner triangles covers the convex hull of the vertices, then it is still point-set triangulation of the vertices, correct?

Comment: Provided that the outer polygon is convex, yes I think so.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you want to summarize your comments into an answer, I'd be happy to upvote it and mark it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't feel it's complete and authoritative enough to be an answer.  Hopefully, someone more knowledgeable that I will come along and write a good answer.  Glad to help.